# View messages on Kafka topic that is listed on a Kamon dashboard

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic, kamon

I can see a Kafka topic on a Kamon dashboard. How do I now view what messages are on the topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have the correct permissions so couldn't view the messages tab. Once granted this was visible.